# Langevin equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, molecular-dynamics

A molecule consists of two atoms whose centers are located at $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $\mathbf{r}_2$ respectively. The atoms are connected by a bond that can be approximated by a
harmonic spring, so that its energy as a function of the separation between the atoms $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2$
is $$U(r) = \frac{akTr^2}{2}$$

Assuming that the molecule lives in one dimension, what will be the overdamped [Langevin equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation)(s) for the motion of the molecule?

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show your work, otherwise it will be a candidate for being closed.